# Postfix configuration / Multiple virtual host

Tags: postfix, domain, email, dedicated-server

I rent a server couple of month ago, but i never managed to configure correclty postfix.

I explain, i have 4 domains, hosted appart from the dedicaced domain and i want to recieve/send mail to my mail client (thunderbird).

Right now, the only thing which is working is the `mail()` working (which is sending mail via postfix).

I'm well aware that i need to install + setup roundcube + changing the "mx" (redirecting the IP to my dedicaced server)

But i can't find any comprehensive tutorial to configure postfix with my 4 domains and handle the sending / recieving process

If you can help me, thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to setup something like that on my Ubuntu Linux VPS, I follow this how-to:

Ubuntu: http://howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-ubuntu-10.04

CentOS: http://howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-centos-5.3-x86_64

I've done this on a handful of servers, and it makes it very easy to administer and is pretty secure from letting postfix act as an open relay.

Comment: i've got a debian, is it similar ? plus, on the website i saw 'iRedMail' have you heard of it ? Thanks4helping

Comment: ok i found if for debian : http://howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-debian-lenny

Comment: Ubuntu and debian are pretty similar. But, HowToForge will have documentation for both of them. Glad you found it - HowToForge is a great resource for a lot of software setups for Linux, too.